# When you join tables, do the tables have to have the same column name?

Tags: sql

When you have two tables something like this

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, 
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

do both tables have to share a column name , like in this example they share CustomerID column?

Comment: Are you talking explicitly about the case when you are joining two tables?

Comment: would it be a difference?

Comment: Different joins will have different behaviors. AFAIK you do not NEED to join on a column, but this can cause odd behavior. Does that answer your question? I can do a full writeup, too :)

Comment: Those two tables do *not* share a column named `customers`.  Do you mean `CustomerID`?

Comment: @larrylustig yes sorry thats what i meant

Comment: You do realise that your title talks about UNION and then your question talks about JOIN, right?

Comment: wow yes, just realize that , silly mistake since im also looking at UNIONS right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's not a `UNION`, it's a `JOIN`.  There is a `UNION` operation in SQL, but it means something different.

If your question is "Do the columns on which I `JOIN` my data have to have the same name" the answer is no.  You could write:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, 
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.PurchasedByID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

if those were the names in your two tables.

On the other hand, if you question is "Do I need to connect the two tables together with a column from one table matching the value in a column in the other table when I do a `JOIN`?" then the answer is also no.  However, a `JOIN` without linked columns will probably not give the results expected -- the number of records in the result set will be equal to the number of records in the first table *multiplied by* the number of records in the second table.  This is called the Cartesian Product of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

The tables don't have to have any columns that are named the same for the join, the ON x = y tells SQL what columns are critical for the join. However, if any two columns have the same name, when you reference them you have to specify the table that they come from, or SQL will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The column name does not matter - you can join on any existing columns. That said, it is a good practice to make sensible joins obvious - you don't want to have a column in one table called "CustomerDataNumbers" that joins to a column in another table called "CustomerID", since it would make a lot more sense to just call both columns "CustomerID" (or something similar). Joins are incredibly powerful... pretty much anything will work, as long as the syntax is correct.

You should note that a join is different from a union. A join will merge the *columns* from two sets of data given a set of rules that govern the join - a union will merge the *rows* from each data set together.